# Why does not working version in asp.net core controller

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, version

I want to use api version in my .net core project.Then search web and find that's solution.
Even though do exactly all solutions,but I can't get desired result.
So if any can help me,Please show me..
I add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 4.0.0 Package in my project and ..

**StartUp.cs**
[image]

[image]

Then in my Controller Add Rout Attribute as Shown :

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[Controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class SellerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBus _client;
    private readonly string AppBaseUrl = MyHttpContext.AppBaseUrl;
    //private readonly IGetUrl _globalUrl;

    public SellerController(IBus client/*, IGetUrl globalUrl*/)
    {
        _client = client;
        //_globalUrl = globalUrl;
    }

    
    [HttpGet("/Sellers/{SellerId}")] // Dashboard   
    public async Task<IActionResult> Info(long SellerId)
    {
           ...
    }
}
```

With these code I expected that I can send request to 'Info' method by this url :
[image]

But that's not working and get 404 error code status.. when I delete "/v1.0" from url and send request, that's working. I will be glad to help me .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, we can find that you applied `[HttpGet("/Sellers/{SellerId}")]` with route
template begin with `/` to `Info` action method, which don't get combined with route templates applied to the controller. To make request to 'Info' method, you could use below URL.

```
https://localhost:5090/sellers/17
```

> I expected that I can send request to 'Info' method by this url : https://localhost:5090/v1.0/sellers/17

To achieve your requirement, you can try to modify the code like below.

```
[HttpGet("/v{version:apiVersion}/Sellers/{SellerId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Info(long SellerId)
{
    //...
    //for testing purpose

    return Ok(SellerId);
}
```

Test Result

[image]

***Update:***

If you'd like to include `v{version:apiVersion}` in route template of controller level attribute routing, you can try to apply `[HttpGet("{SellerId}")]` to `Info` action method and make request with `https://localhost:5090/v1.0/seller/17`.

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[Controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class SellerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{SellerId}")] // Dashboard   
    public async Task<IActionResult> Info(long SellerId)
    {
        //...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.By your solution,I need to add that route to every method in controller.But I do not intend to do this.and There is another issue..How is diagnosis api Version in this solution..??

Comment: You can check my update, and make request with `https://localhost:5090/v1.0/seller/17`.